# Facebook Deep Linking on iOS not starting my app

Tags: ios, facebook, deep-linking

I'm trying to implement Facebook's Deep Linking feature in order to launch game directly when the user taps a story in the native Facebook app. I've configured and enabled Deep Linking. I've then posted on my timeline using my app, it's a link to my game's site. The link contains a special GUID that enables some social activity in-game. When I click the link on web, my website opens normally. When I tap the story in native app, again, my website opens. However, if I tap the `via` part of the story in the bottom (such as `3 hours ago via MyApp`) then my app launches, but it doesn't work for me as the GUID is not passed that way to the app (and also it would be useless to expect people to tap that part of the story). How can I set it up such that when the user clicks the link in a web browser, they will be taken to my website where there is a link to my app that they can download, but when they tap the same link in native Facebook App (only iOS is concerned), the game will launch and the link will be passed to my game? I don't know why it doesn't take me to the app when I click the link.

Here is a screenshot from my app's dashboard:

[image: dashboard]

The URL scheme suffix is only for if I want to use the same ID for multiple apps, which is not the case.

Comment: Check if you have configured the url scheme (FB[AppID]://) in info.plist . When you enable sso, deep linking in Fb app settings , when user taps on the story, link would be passed inside target_url param. Keep a break point in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation` to see if the url passed by FB contains the target_url param

Comment: my URL scheme is configured correctly, and SSO is already working properly. i can't test that code for two reasons: 1) i'm using flash with adobe air to create my game, 2) the problem is already that my app is not launching at all, so even if i was on xcode/obj-c i couldn't test it. but my app uses SSO and it works perfectly. my app is invoked, and i capture the access token at the invoke event.

Comment: It sounds like you have linking, but only shallow linking - i.e. your app is known, but for some reason the link in the native app is to the web site. (The 'via' name, as you point out, is not where people should be clicking).

I guess I should check you read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/link-to-your-native-app-ios-sdk/ and implemented application openURL? And everything is configured correctly in the Facebook app dashboard?

Comment: @James Pearce hello, as i've said before, i can't use openURL as I'm working with Flash/Adobe AIR, not xcode/cocoa/objc. for the app's dashboard, i've updated the question with a screenshot

Comment: @canpoyrazoğlu : ignore if this seems irrelevant. 
But i would suggest try giving the iPhone App store ID same as iPad .
Reason: While i am trying out tap on FB Notifications, i observed that if the app store id of the app is not mentioned it takes to the website , irrespective of app installed or not. When i mentioned app store id , its taking me to app store irrespective of app install dot not(becoz i disabled depp linking)

Comment: as it's an iPad only app, when I try to add iphone id i get this error: Error

Your iPhone App Store ID is invalid because the iTunes App Store reports your app as being unavailable for iPhone and iPod touch.

Comment: Same issue here, on 6.0 running off of Xcode 4.5.1. It's setup correctly on FB, but FB opens the URL instead of opening app.

Comment: Hi there. Have you found a solution? I'm experiencing exactly the same issue: I can launch my app by tapping on the (via ...) link, but tapping on the post itself just launches the browser. Been trying to figure out what's wrong for a couple of days now.

Comment: well, haven't been on this project for a while. just checked, and tapping the post launched the game.. but haven't changed anything. maybe it's just a time delay issue